# Can Wordpress handle multi-site CiviCRM the same way Drupal 7 with domain access does?

Tags: wordpress, multisite, drupal-multi-site

My organization is currently running a multi-site CiviCRM deployment on Drupal 7 using the domain access module.

We set permissions on the contacts by using the state field so that the leadership in a state can only see that state's contacts.

Some states also have home pages with custom content and menus, but use the bulk of the national web site as "background" content.

The above configuration has served us well for several years now, but we keep getting push back from states that Drupal is too hard to use and people aren't posting content for that reason.

Can we replicate this same functionality on the WordPress platform? If not, how close can we get?

Comment: is it not possible to make some simple UI improvements to help users add content more easily?

Comment: I echo the comment from @petednz-fuzion.  It could be a lot of work to rebuild your site in WordPress.  If possible I would look at what you can do to improve the Drupal interface and make it more user friendly.  In my experience WordPress isn't necessarily more user friendly.  With good configuration Drupal can provide a better user interface. It all depends on how well the system is set up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - this can be done - you will find instructions on how to integrate Civi with a WordPress Multisite installation [**HERE**](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/multi-site/#wordpress-multisites).

Hope this helps!